# Problems accesing invisible field data in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Hello everybody and thanks in advance for taking the time to read my question.

This is my scenario:

I have a `DataGridView` were I display some values from a table with a PK `Id`. I don't want to display the `Id` field, but still to be able to Access the value into `Id` to perform a `DELETE` statement on my database.

I have hidden that `Id` field with the instruction: `DataGridView.Columns("Id").Visible = False`

The `Id` field is the first on the DataGridView, so it gets the index 0 when it is selected.

If I try to get its value trough `DataGrid.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value`
the program throws an exception.

I have tested the same code without using `DataGridView.Columns("Id").Visible = False` and it works perfectly, so I asume that the function `DataGrid.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value` can't work if the field that corresponds to `Item(0)` is not visible.

I need to select the `Id` directly from the `DataGridView` since its `Id` variates with each row.

Any different approach to this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting? You might want to try something like this: Dim val As String = dgv.SelectedCells(0).Value.ToString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
If Not IsNothing(DataGrid.CurrentRow) Then
Dim intId As Integer = DataGrid.CurrentRow.Cells("Id").Value
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to hide columns or refer to the grid at all in code. Start by adding the columns you do want to the grid in the designer. Set the `DataPropertyName` of each column to tell it which data source column to bind to.

In code, use an `OleDbDataAdapter` to populate a `DataTable` and then bind that to the grid via a `BindingSource`. Whenever you want to delete the current record, call `RemoveCurrent` on the `BindingSource`. That will flag the row as `Deleted` and hide it from the UI.

Once you've made all the changes you want to make, call `Update` on the same data adapter to save the changes from the `DataTable` back to the database in a batch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Tag in a row to store information instead of a hidden column.

For example:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(sID).Tag = Your id.
```